# How do I vertically align sets of radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css.

I have 3 sets of radio buttons.  Each set of buttons is displayed in a singe line.  I would like the buttons to align vertically between sets of buttons.  I am having trouble accomplishing this with css.  I would like to avoid using tables to solve this problem.  I figured I could get the radio buttons aligned by setting the width of their labels, but it doesn't work.

My radio buttons display like this:

[image: misaligned radio buttons]

I want them to display like this:

[image: aligned radio buttons]

Here's my css:

```
form.remit_change_form label.fixedwidth {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}

form.remit_change_form input.radiolabel {
    width: 35px /* doesn't make any visual change! */
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<div>
  <label for="tran_code" class="fixedwidth">Tran Code</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="tran_code" id="tran_code_22" 
    value="22"/>
  <label for="tran_code_22" class="radiolabel">22</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="tran_code" id="tran_code_42" 
    value="42"/>
  <label for="tran_code_42" class="radiolabel">42</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="tran_code" id="tran_code_52" 
    value="52"/>
  <label for="tran_code_52" class="radiolabel">52</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="tran_code" id="tran_code_na" 
    value="NA"/>
  <label for="tran_code_na" class="radiolabel">NA</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="cut_off_time" class="fixedwidth">Cut-off Time</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="cut_off_time" id="cut_off_time_18.00" 
    value="18.00"/>
  <label for="cut_off_time_18.00" class="radiolabel">18.00</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="cut_off_time" id="cut_off_time_19.00" 
    value="19.00"/>
  <label for="cut_off_time_19.00" class="radiolabel">19.00</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="cut_off_time" id="cut_off_time_na" 
    value="NA"/>
  <label for="cut_off_time_na" class="radiolabel">NA</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="remit_notify_method" class="fixedwidth">Remit Notify Method</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="remit_notify_method" 
    id="remit_notify_method_n" value="N"/>
  <label for="remit_notify_method_n" class="radiolabel">N</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="remit_notify_method" 
    id="remit_notify_method_f" value="F"/>
  <label for="remit_notify_method_f" class="radiolabel">F</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioinput" name="remit_notify_method" 
    id="remit_notify_method_e" value="E"/>
  <label for="remit_notify_method_e" class="radiolabel">E</label>
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered putting them in a table?

Comment: I advice against using tables if its not tabular data, especially when it's not complicated achieving it in css

Comment: This is a near-perfect spot for a table. Maybe you too have been terrorized by the Layout Police :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use classes, if not otherwise needed (**edit**: they were needed, so answer has been updated).

```
form.remit_change_form label.radiolabel
{
    display:inline-block; /* added this */
    width: 50px;
}

form.remit_change_form label.fixedwidth {
    width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: This works.  Do you mind if I edit the answer before I accept it?  I don't need the css rule for `form.remit_change_form input[type=radio]` as the default width is fine.  I need to change the the rule for `form.remit_change_form label` to `form.remit_change_form label.radiolabel`, otherwise my checkbox labels are squeezed.

Comment: The short form of this answer is that I needed to add `display:inline-block` to my rule for `form.remit_change_form label.radiolabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give yourself some more HTML elements to work with? If you're opposed to using tables, how about using an unordered list?

http://jsfiddle.net/YYjsT/

Comment: Nice work.  But this doesn't display how I requested.  
These buttons are part of a much larger form, displaying like this breaks the flow of the rest of the form.

Comment: This worked well for stacking radios vertically. Very simple yet effective.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in a table works nicely

http://jsfiddle.net/3QJg8/

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 the answers that use tables as the question specifically states that I don't want to use them (and implies that I know how).  But I won't vote them down because I acknowledge you answered in good faith.  I think the spot to argue for tables would be in the comments under the question.